# Running linux shell script with PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, shell-exec

I have created shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/upload/ftp/$1.ifc"
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "Found."
else
    echo "Not found."
fi
IfcConvert --use-element-guids /home/upload/ftp/${1}.ifc /home/upload/ftp/${1}.dae
```

When I go to linux terminal and execute it from there with

```
./script.sh drevodomek
```

everything works fine.. I got "Found." message and also converter executes

But when I created helper.php

```
<?php
if (file_exists("/home/upload/ftp/drevodomek.ifc"))  
{ 
    echo "The file exists"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "The file does not exists"; 
}

$cmd = "./script.sh drevodomek";
$results = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $results
?>
```

I get answers:

"The file exists." from PHP,

"Found." from script.sh

IfcConvert: input file "/home/upload/ftp/drevodomek.ifc" doesn't exists. from script.sh

I am new to linux, has anyone any idea what is the difference running script from terminal and with shell_exec()? Thanks!

Comment: Try to use the absolute path to the script rather than assuming the current directory of the PHP instance is the one the script resides in (it likely doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the rights, seems like terminal was run as root, but php exetuted script as normal user. Always check your 777!